# Translate non-digital characters to specific digits

Tags: php, string, numbers, translation, converters

Is it possible to convert characters in a string into specific numbers like

```
a = 1,  // uppercase too
b = 2,  
c = 3,  
d = 4,  
e = 5,  // and so on til letter 'z'

space = 0 // I'm not sure about if space really is equals to 0
```

Here's how I think it goes.

```
$string_1 = "abed";   // only string
$string_2 = "abed 5"; // with int

$result_1 = convert_to_int($string_1); // output is 1254
$result_2 = convert_to_int($string_2); // output is 125405
```

Comment: What about capital letters? Is `A` 1 as well?

Comment: Yes, mybad didn't think of it. I edited it so others will not be confused about the case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array, and insert a space to the first element. Then use `range()` to generate an array with `a` to `z`. Use `strtolower()` to force the input to lowercase (as the characters from `range()` we generate is lowercase too.

Then do a replacement with `str_replace()`, which accepts arrays as values. The keys is the value that the value will be replaced with.

```
function convert_to_int($string) {;
    $characters = array_merge([' '], range('a', 'z'));
    return str_replace(array_values($characters), array_keys($characters), $string);
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/cHZap

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code:

```
$s = 'abcde';
$p = str_split($s);
foreach($p as $c) {
    echo ord($c) - ord('a') + 1;
}
```

Comment: does it apply to a-z as well?

Answer (score 1):

To use the numbers that you have shown `a = 1` etc... then just do a case-insensitive replace:

```
$result = str_ireplace(range('a', 'z'), range(1, 26), $string);
```

If you want the ASCII value then split to an array, map to the `ord` value and join:

```
$result = implode(array_map(function($v) { return ord($v); }, str_split($string)));
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform a **str**ing **tr**anslation, the most appropriate native function is `strtr()`.

If you don't need to translate to double digit numbers, to can pass two correlated strings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XQaad))

```
echo strtr('abcde 5', ' abcde', '012345');
// 1234505
```

If you need to accommodate the full alphabet, then declare an associative array of string keys to numeric values.  The map can be manually written or populated with a variety of native functions.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rIrEq))

```
$map = [];
array_push($map, ' ', ...range("a", "z"));
echo strtr('abcde 5', array_flip($map));
// 1234505
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
echo strtr('abcde 5', array_flip(array_merge([' '], range("a", "z"))));
```

To accommodate uppercase charactets, simply call `strtolower()` on the input string before translating.

Relevant reading:

- [Converting large numbers into letters (and back again)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52788127/2943403)
- [Create unique string from id to build an link shortening system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/246255/141885)

Answer (score -1):

Using regex should be like this:

```
$search  = array('/[A-a]/', '/[B-b]/', '/[C-c]/', '/[D-d]/', '/[" "]/');
$replace = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');

$final = preg_replace($search, $replace,"abcd ABCD a55");

echo $final;

Output: 1234512345155
```